# Leiningen repl EOF exception in project

Tags: windows, clojure, leiningen

Just installed Leiningen 2.1.2 (lein.bat) on Windows XP in D:\lein\, added this dir to path.

Then I started repl

```
D:\lein>lein repl
```

and it runs fine.

Also it runs in other dir and can execute commands well.

Then i made sample project 'helloworld':

```
D:\lein>lein new app helloworld
```

Lein made project dir with sample app.

Then I go to project dir with

```
D:\lein>cd helloworld
```

And now i run command inside project folder:

```
D:\lein\helloworld>lein repl
```

and get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" clojure.lang.LispReader$ReaderException: java.lang.Ru
ntimeException: EOF while reading string
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.read(LispReader.java:220)
    at clojure.core$read.invoke(core.clj:3407)
    at clojure.core$read.invoke(core.clj:3405)
    at clojure.main$eval_opt$fn__6602.invoke(main.clj:306)
    at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:306)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:327)
    at clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:353)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:440)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:3894)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:527)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:410)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: EOF while reading string
    at clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException(Util.java:219)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader$StringReader.invoke(LispReader.java:461)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.readDelimitedList(LispReader.java:1148)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader$ListReader.invoke(LispReader.java:982)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.readDelimitedList(LispReader.java:1148)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader$ListReader.invoke(LispReader.java:982)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.readDelimitedList(LispReader.java:1148)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader$ListReader.invoke(LispReader.java:982)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.readDelimitedList(LispReader.java:1148)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader$ListReader.invoke(LispReader.java:982)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.readDelimitedList(LispReader.java:1148)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader$ListReader.invoke(LispReader.java:982)
    at clojure.lang.LispReader.read(LispReader.java:185)
    ... 12 more
Exception in thread "Thread-1" clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Subprocess failed {:e
xit-code 1}
    at clojure.core$ex_info.invoke(core.clj:4327)
    at leiningen.core.eval$fn__2654.invoke(eval.clj:213)
    at clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke(MultiFn.java:231)
    at leiningen.core.eval$eval_in_project.invoke(eval.clj:283)
    at leiningen.repl$start_server.invoke(repl.clj:117)
    at leiningen.repl$server$fn__6110.invoke(repl.clj:173)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:159)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:617)
    at clojure.core$with_bindings_STAR_.doInvoke(core.clj:1788)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:621)
    at clojure.core$bound_fn_STAR_$fn__4102.doInvoke(core.clj:1810)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
REPL server launch timed out.
```

I feel I missed something or my system messed somehow. Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED

Installed JDK instead of JRE and it works ok.

ALSO

Problem can raise when 'java.exe' from jre-s comes first on the path, i have cleaned system by recursively looking 'where' java.exe is and removing its presence from path everywhere except jdk path.

It can be :

1. under windows\system32 folder /just delete it from there
2. under jdk-s path-s /just remove that path-s from $PATH variable

Answer (score 1):

You have to change lein version in your script **lein.bat**  from 2.1.3 to 2.1.0 **LEIN_VERSION=2.1.0** then enter the command **lein self-install** in the command prompt

Comment: For me it looks like more better way to set system properly, then it will work smoothly in future.

Comment: the problem persists even if with JDK.

Comment: it can be if 'java.exe' from jre comes first on the path, then it needs to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

- remove directory %home%.lein with all contents/files under it
- download win installer http://leiningen-win-installer.djpowell.net/
- install leiningen
- run repl like this:

  [WINKEY + R]
  CMD.EXE [ENTER]
  C:>\ lein repl

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from jdk 1.6 to jdk 1.7 fixed that problem for me.